# Add identity to existing aurelia .net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aurelia, identity

I have followed this guide https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices to create an asp .net core 2 aurelia project.

But I would like to add identity to this project but I can't find a good guide how to do it...

Anyone who has done this or have an idea where I can start?

Best regards
Andreas

Comment: I have read something about Identity as UI

Answer (score 3):

*Edit:* since I felt this question requires more explanation, I wrote a [blog post](https://miroslavpopovic.com/posts/2018/07/aspnet-core-identity-and-aurelia) and a [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/miroslavpopovic/aspnetcore-aurelia-sample).

---

Depending on how far you want to go down the rabbit hole, you could either:

1. Reimplement the whole ASP.NET Core Identity UI in Aurelia.
2. Have the default implementation of Identity in MVC.
3. Have something in between, like have login only implemented in Aurelia and the rest (registration, forgot password, management, etc) implemented in MVC.

For most of my projects, I simply create a new ASP.NET Core MVC app with Identity and then add Aurelia to it (within the same or separate project). Security is hard and it's easy to mess something up. If you leave the default Identity implementation, you can serve Aurelia app via default route (`/home/index`) and have `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller or action method to require users to log in before accessing it.

At one point I was thinking about #1, to create a sample app (or even a .NET Core template) with entire Identity UI re-implemented in Aurelia and blog about it, but of course, time was an issue and I never started it.

So, my suggestion is to go with #2.

If you are on ASP.NET Core 2.1 (and you really should upgrade to it, since 2.0 end of life comes in [a few months](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/20/net-core-2-0-will-reach-end-of-life-on-september-1-2018/)), there are some Identity changes that might help you. Identity in 2.1 is implemented as [a separate Razor Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.1?view=aspnetcore-2.1#identity-ui-library--scaffolding), which is a new feature in ASP.NET Core 2.1.

You can find more details about how to scaffold Identity to existing ASP.NET Core projects in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out.
I have targetframework = netcoreapp2.0

So I think i might update the project to 2.1 first.

Comment: `<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>`

I have like this in my _Layout.cshtml page. But I want that you have to login before you can access the website. How can I make that happend? @MiroslavPopovic

Comment: @AndreasPettersson if you have Authentication middleware enabled in your `Startup` class and Identity configured, it's just a matter of adding `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller or action method that serves the Aurelia app. It will redirect the unauthenticated user to Identity login page. The best way to check how it works is to create a new ASP.NET Core MVC app with Identity enabled (individual user accounts).

Comment: Okay, thanks. 

I just want that you can log in, not create account. But on the log in page there was a button that you can register a new account. But I did not find the view so I can't change so the button disappear.

You said you have added aurelia to an existing project, do you have a good tutorial for that? I though if I create a new asp .net core 2.1 project with individual user accounts and then add aurelia to that project.

Comment: That is the change in 2.1. Identity views are now added through the Razor library (separate assembly). You can scaffold them though - this is a good tutorial: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-scaffold-identity-ui-in-asp-net-core-2-1/. As for adding Aurelia to an existing ASP.NET Core project, I don't remember if I saw any tutorial for that. It shouldn't be too hard to just use `au new` within the same folder to initialize it and then manually include it to Razor view(s). That's how I did it on a few projects.

Comment: Okay thanks, `<body> @RenderBody() @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) </body>` 

I have like this in my Layout page. But on the tutorial it looks like this:

 `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a asp-page="/Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-page="/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
            </div>`

Where should i put the partial view?

Comment: That's the navigation menu with a partial view for adding the link to login/logout... It's hard to explain what everything does through these comments. I'll try to create a sample on GitHub tomorrow or over the weekend and let you know.

Comment: Oh nice! I have followed this guide to create an aurelia app: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices
But I dont understand where I should put the loginpartial view. Becasuse my navigation comes from app.ts

Comment: Hey @AndreasPettersson, I have updated the answer with links to my blog post and sample code on GitHub. I hope it will help.